# Assign Public IP address to an instance through cloud-formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

This cloud formation template works as per my expectations. But when I enable Private IP address parameter, I get an error.

```
{
   "Resources":{
      "MySpotFleet":{
         "Type":"AWS::EC2::SpotFleet",
         "Properties":{
            "SpotFleetRequestConfigData":{
               "IamFleetRole": "arn:aws:iam::513469704633:role/aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role",
               "SpotPrice":"1",
               "TargetCapacity":"1",
               "LaunchSpecifications":[
                  {
                     "InstanceType":"t2.small",
                     "ImageId":"ami-009d6802948d06e52",
                     #"PrivateIpAddress": "18.208.241.12"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

How do I assign a specific elastic IP address to the newly created spot instance?

If the answer is through UserData then how to mention user-data string in this template? (I have a few other commands in user-data file)

---

Update:

I tried to set the IP address using user-data. Spot instance was created using this script, but without any Public IP address.

```
{
   "Resources":{
      "MySpotFleet":{
         "Type":"AWS::EC2::SpotFleet",
         "Properties":{
            "SpotFleetRequestConfigData":{
               "IamFleetRole": "arn:aws:iam::513469704633:role/aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role",
               "SpotPrice":"1",
               "TargetCapacity":"1",
               "LaunchSpecifications":[
                  {
                     "InstanceType":"t2.small",
                     "ImageId":"ami-009d6802948d06e52",
                     #"PrivateIpAddress": "18.208.241.12"
        "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
          "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
"pip install aws-ec2-assign-elastic-ip\n",
"aws-ec2-assign-elastic-ip --access-key xxx --secret-key xxx --valid-ips 18.208.241.12\n"
        ]]}}
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to add user-data parameter and the final code looks like this:

```
{
   "Resources":{
      "MySpotFleet":{
         "Type":"AWS::EC2::SpotFleet",
         "Properties":{
            "SpotFleetRequestConfigData":{
               "IamFleetRole":"arn:aws:iam::513469704633:role/aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role",
               "SpotPrice":"1",
               "TargetCapacity":"1",
               "LaunchSpecifications":[
                  {
                     "InstanceType":"t2.small",
                     "ImageId":"ami-009d6802948d06e52",
                     "KeyName":"dec15a",
                     "BlockDeviceMappings":[
                        {
                           "DeviceName":"/dev/xvda",
                           "Ebs":{
                              "VolumeSize":100,
                              "VolumeType":"gp2"
                           }
                        }
                     ],

                   "UserData": {
 "Fn::Base64": {
 "Fn::Sub": 
          "#!/bin/bash -xe\n
           yum install -y docker mysql git python-pip\n  
           pip install aws-ec2-assign-elastic-ip\n 
           sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y docker\n
           aws-ec2-assign-elastic-ip --access-key xxx --secret-key xxx --valid-ips 18.208.241.12\n
           service docker start\n"
                    }
 },

                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice, however never ever embed access and secret keys to your templates. Use **[EC2 Instance IAM Role](https://aws.nz/best-practice/ec2-instance-roles/)** that gives it the required permissions instead (yes it can be done through CloudFormation).

Comment: Also you seem to be doing some *docker* stuff - consider [AWS ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) instead of running docker directly. It will make your life easier.

Comment: How do I create a role "aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role" using cloudformation template?

Comment: you’ll need `AWS::IAM::Role` resource in the template. If you need more details open a new question and I will answer there.